# MySQL fulltext or exact value search is very slow

Tags: mysql, indexing, full-text-search

I have this table of 9.5 million rows and I need to perform both fulltext and exact value search over the same column.

Altho there are 2 indexes over this column, one BTREE, one FULLTEXT, database engine doesn't use any and goes thru all 9.5M rows.

```sql
select * from mytable
where match(document) against ('+111/05257' in boolean mode)
   or document = '111/05257';
-- very slow, takes ~ 9 seconds
-- possible keys: both
-- used key: none :(
```

If I use only one type of search, queries run fast.

```sql
select * from mytable where document = '111/05257';
-- very fast, around 80 ms
-- used key: btree
```

```sql
select * from mytable where match(document) against ('+111/05257' in boolean mode)
-- very fast, around 100 ms
-- used key: fulltext
```

Given poorly structured data at document column, ranging from '1/XA' thru '5778292019' to 'S:NXA/0001/XA2019/111/05257', I **need to use both exact and partial (fulltext) search** over this column.

Wildcard searches ('%111/05257%') also perform terribly over btree index.

Any idea how to solve this?

Thank you all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Queries involving `OR` are notoriously hard to optimize. A common solution is to change them into two queries, and UNION the results:

```
select * from mytable
where match(document) against ('+111/05257' in boolean mode)
UNION
select * from mytable
where document = '111/05257';
```

Each of the respective queries should be free to use a different index.  The `UNION` will eliminate any rows in common from the two results.

Comment: Brilliant, this union query takes about 120 ms :-) Thank you

Comment: Get rid of the second SELECT; the first should find the rows.

Comment: @RickJames, in this case, yes. But, per original question, the column's data are poorly structured, and I need to use both fulltext and exact search, bc fulltext wouldn't match values like "1/XA"

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' -- Consider using two separate queries -- first with MATCH; if nothing found with it, then execute the second (with LIKE).  The FT will usually be fast; the LIKE will always be slow.